# Getting href attribute as written with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I would like to get an href attribute as it appears in the html - instead of a fully qualified url.

```
<a href="foo.html">foo</a>

$('a[href]').each(function(){
   alert(this.href);
});
```

Gets an absolute url starting with http://  .  I'd like it to get "foo.html" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to alter the way you loop through the element, and the way you use `this`:

```
$('a').each(function(){
   alert( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );
});
```

[Working example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/QXrh5/1/)

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I need to do more reading on JQuery. Each time I think, I get it - it tricks me again!

Answer (score 2):

Try `.attr('href')` to get the href value.

Comment: this.attr() generates an error.  Are you suggeting, drop this and go with naked .attr?

Comment: By `.attr` I meant `$(this).attr('href')`, since `this` is a reference to the DOMElement which does NOT have an attr method, but when wrapped with jQuery it does.